# ¿Puedo ejecutar una aplicación de Laravel que cloné de github sin tener instalado Composer ni Laravel?

Tags: laravel

Cloné de GitHub una aplicación desarrollada en Laravel, pero no tengo instalado ni Composer ni Laravel ¿Es necesario tenerlos instalados para poder ejecutar la aplicación?

Cabe mencionar que cuando ejecuto

```
php artisan serve
```

me arroja un error fatal

Comment: es necesario instalar composer porque en git no se guardan las dependencias que necesita tu proyecto

Answer (score 1):

No necesitas tener instalado Laravel como paquete global (que sólo se usa para generar aplicaciones, diría yo) y de todos modos eso se haría con composer, así que no va a suceder.

Si no tienes composer, la aplicación funcionará únicamente si en el repositorio clonado se ha incluído bajo control de versiones la carpeta `vendor` y, obviamente, que la aplicación desde donde se hizo lo anterior funcione.

El flujo para que esto funcione con eventuales actualizaciones del repo original no es tan intuitivo si quisieras mantener limpia la rama en que trabajas y deployar en un branch creado únicamente para tal propósito. Si en tu rama principal o en la rama `deploy` añades la carpeta `vendor` con

```
git add --force vendor
git commit vendor -m "agregando miles de dependencias, damn!"
```

los paquetes nuevos o actualizados en la fuente pasarán desapercibidos, luego tendrías que crear un `git hook` que ejecute lo anterior cuando intentes hacer un push, o un composer script que lo haga después de un install, remove o update.

Si quitas la carpeta del `.gitignore` en la rama deploy ésta desaparecerá al volver a `master` y, si luego de reinstalar las dependencias en `master` intentas volver a la rama `deploy` te arrojará un error del tipo:

```
error: Los siguientes archivos sin seguimiento en el árbol de trabajo serán sobrescritos al actualizar el árbol de trabajo:
bla blah
```

por lo que sería más sano eliminar la rama deploy y recrearla cuando se necesite, ejem, deployar.

¿Muy rebuscado? **te sugiero otro camino, aunque no responde específicamente a tu pregunta:**

Si tu problemática es que la máquina remota no permite instalar composer siempre puedes bajar el `phar` y ejecutarlo localmente en la raíz del repositorio,

en vez de

```
composer install
```

en tu remoto, luego de clonar, ejecutarías

```
wget https://getcomposer.org/download/2.0.12/composer.phar
php composer.phar install
```

o bien puedes hacer el .phar ejecutable e invocarlo directamente

```
 wget https://getcomposer.org/download/2.0.12/composer.phar
 chmod +x composer.phar
 ./composer.phar install
```

Todo esto se basa en suposiciones porque no nos contaste las razones que explican tu necesidad.